# Query max time (latest) by id SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a similar table:

```
ID     | Name    | Time
-------|---------|-----------------------------
111    | AAA     | 2015-11-05 15:39:24.000
222    | BBB     | 2015-11-04 11:29:11.000
111    | AAA     | 2015-11-02 13:12:10.000
333    | CCC     | 2015-11-05 15:39:24.000
111    | AAA     | 2015-11-01 15:39:24.000
```

I would like to get the latest `Time` for every `ID`. My output would look something like this:

```
ID     | Name    | Time
-------|---------|-----------------------------
111    | AAA     | 2015-11-05 15:39:24.000
222    | BBB     | 2015-11-04 11:29:11.000
333    | CCC     | 2015-11-05 15:39:24.000
```

Please help me formulate the query!

Can I use `max(Time)` to get latest `Time`?
Do I need to JOIN the table with itself to be able to list `max(Time)` for all `ID`s?

Comment: `select max(time),id,name from tablename group by id,name`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there are more columns you want to keep you could use a CTE with `ROW_NUMBER` function:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT Id, Name, Time, OtherColumns...,
           RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID Order By Time DESC)
    FROM dbo.TableName
)
SELECT Id, Name, Time, OtherColumns...
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

If it's possible that there are mutliple rows with the same max-time per ID and you want all of them instead of one arbitrary replace `ROW_NUMBER` with `DENSE_RANK`. [Ranking Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798(v=sql.120).aspx)

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER()` as rn will skip data with the same MAX Time like: `111,'AAA','2015-11-05 15:39:24.000'` and `111,'DDD','2015-11-05 15:39:24.000'`. How about **RANK()** instead? [Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/384590)

Answer (score 2):

Use `MAX` function to find the latest time.

**Query**

```
SELECT ID, Name,
     MAX(Time) AS [Time]
FROM your_table_name
GROUP BY ID, Name;
```

Comment: Thanks for the simple and quick solution!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MAX` function:

```
SELECT ID, Name, MAX([Time]) AS [Time]
FROM your_table
GROUP BY ID, Name ;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/384565)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═════╦══════╦═════════════════════╗
║ ID  ║ Name ║        Time         ║
╠═════╬══════╬═════════════════════╣
║ 111 ║ AAA  ║ 2015-11-05 15:39:24 ║
║ 222 ║ BBB  ║ 2015-11-04 11:29:11 ║
║ 333 ║ CCC  ║ 2015-11-05 15:39:24 ║
╚═════╩══════╩═════════════════════╝
```

There is one catch though, data you provided has the same ID/NAME pairs. With different data you will get:

```
INSERT INTO #Your_Table(ID,Name,Time) VALUES (111,'AAA','2015-11-05 15:39:24.000');
INSERT INTO #Your_Table(ID,Name,Time) VALUES (222,'BBB','2015-11-04 11:29:11.000');
INSERT INTO #Your_Table(ID,Name,Time) VALUES (111,'AAA','2015-11-02 13:12:10.000');
INSERT INTO #Your_Table(ID,Name,Time) VALUES (333,'CCC','2015-11-05 15:39:24.000');
INSERT INTO #Your_Table(ID,Name,Time) VALUES (111,'DDD','2015-11-01 15:39:24.000');
```

Output:

```
╔═════╦══════╦═════════════════════╗
║ ID  ║ Name ║        Time         ║
╠═════╬══════╬═════════════════════╣
║ 111 ║ AAA  ║ 2015-11-05 15:39:24 ║
║ 222 ║ BBB  ║ 2015-11-04 11:29:11 ║
║ 333 ║ CCC  ║ 2015-11-05 15:39:24 ║
║ 111 ║ DDD  ║ 2015-11-01 15:39:24 ║
╚═════╩══════╩═════════════════════╝
```

If you want actual row and not result of grouping use like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33522472/5070879):

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT ID, MAX([Time]) AS [Time]
  FROM #your_table
  GROUP BY ID
)
SELECT t.*
FROM #your_table t
JOIN cte c
  ON c.ID = t.ID
 AND c.[Time] = t.[Time]
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/384569)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Your question does not say that you want to get your output based on `NAME`, just `ID`. Therefore the previous answers are technically wrong. You should be using:

```
SELECT ID, AGGREGATEFUNCTION(Name), MAX(Time) AS [Time]
FROM Your_Table
GROUP BY ID
```

This means if your names differ then they will not create a separate group.

It also meets exactly your requirement.

Comment: Before you say `Therefore the previous answers are technically wrong.` Check your answer. It even doesn't works ends up with syntax error: `Column 'Name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: Please note, I am not saying it will not work, just that you are grouping on information he is not asking to, which could cause erroneous results. I overlooked selecting the Name column, thank you for your correction. The idea is to meet exactly the OP requirement. Your query is good, I am looking at this approach because it is **not assuming anything**. However, the OP has contradicted his question by basing on ID only and wanting Name in the selection.

Comment: With your query with data `111 BBB 2015-01-01` and `111 AAA 2015-05-01` he would get `111 BBB 2015-05-01`. The point is that OP wants actual row or aggregated Name

Comment: No, I am leaving the aggregation to the imagination.

Comment: I see only MIN/MAX for textual data eventually some CASE inside

Comment: Yes I suppose a CASE statement would solve this problem too, but here is a decision for the OP. To base the output on a GROUP BY of ID, NAME as this NAME field could differ from matching the ID and cause a problem. Or to insert a CASE statement to account for possibilities inside the AGGREGATE that do not match his desired output.